# Letting macOS sandboxed apps write file created by my non-sandboxed app

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox

I have a macOS/Objective-C/Cocoa application. We want to spawn external applications, like TextEdit, to edit files created by this app. I'm creating these files by copying it into my ~/Documents directory (eventually I'd like to put it elsewhere, but I'm trying to simplify) with:

```
NSFileManager *defaultManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[defaultManager copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:destPath error:&err];
NSDate *sourceModified = [self lastModificationOfFile:srcPath];
NSDictionary * attr = @{ NSFileModificationDate : sourceModified,
                         NSFileImmutable : [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                         NSFilePosixPermissions : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:0666],
                         };
[defaultManager setAttributes:attr ofItemAtPath:destPath error:nil];
```

When I open this file in TextEdit, the window header says "filename.txt - Locked". Editing the document gives me the "Are you sure you want to modify the document in place?" dialog. I select "Overwrite", but then attempts to save give me "The document "filename.txt" could not be saved. You don't have permission."

However, this writes a "filename.txt.sb-a69dcdc5-7V6D2g" (or similarly named) file into my Documents directory. And files created from the bash shell with "echo blablabla > filename.txt" in that same directory open just fine.

I have tried many variations on those attributes. I cannot see any difference between the files which work and those which display "... - Locked" using "ls -la@ filename.txt" or "xattr", even side-by-side in the same directory.

Clearly I'm up against some sandboxing issue with the files I create, but all of my search results are about the other side of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Argh. I found this: [Why does TextEdit open HTML files as locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827083/why-does-textedit-open-html-files-as-locked). Apparently because of the content of my .txt file, TextEdit was interpreting it as an HTML document and treating it differently based on that. Replaced the content of the file with things that didn't look like HTML and I'm able to edit the document now.